# iOS 8.3 in app purchase

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, storekit, xcode6.3, ios8.3

So after updating to iOS 8.3 and xCode 6.3, I'm getting a bug when trying to do an in app purchase. When that Sign In screen pops up, it seems that my game freezes but it doesn't crash. When I click on `cancel` and that message goes away, none of my buttons work. The frame rate and node count at the bottom of the screen is also frozen and it just sits there until I quit the game.

My in app purchase works fine with iOS 8.2 and lower, but after updating to 8.3 this problem happens. Does anyone know what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: Anything special happening in `applicationWillResignActive:`?

Comment: @matt I do have some code to pause the view..  
``SKView *view = (SKView*)self.window.rootViewController.view;
    view.paused = YES;
    ((ELMyScene*)view.scene).gamePaused = YES;``

Comment: Well, when that dialog appears, you _do_ resign active.

Comment: @matt I do have code for ``applicationDidBecomeActive`` to set ``view.paused = YES`` to NO. But it seems like it's not getting called.

Comment: That would be a bug (in the runtime), if the system's presentation of this dialog caused your `applicationWillResignActive:` to be called but dismissal does not cause its `applicationDidBecomeActive:` to be called. If you can verify that, especially if you can verify it in a very very reduced version of your app, you should file a bug report with Apple. (And no, I can't think of a workaround just now, if that is really what's happening.)

Comment: @matt thank you for the help! i will try with Apple.

Comment: Thanks for calling it "help" but I'm afraid I did nothing for you. :(